# How to make faster of a code containing more iteration points?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerical-value, time-series

I am trying to evaluate a code of the Power Series Solution method to get the results. Also, the time of evaluation depends on the parameters I am using. When the iteration point is 50, 60, or 80, it takes less time(10 mins to 1 hour) than when the iteration point is 100 or 120(like two to three days). So is there any code that makes it faster to get the result?
Here is an example. When I am giving the iteration value 100, it takes two days whereas in the case of 40, 50, or 80 it takes 15-20 mins, and for smaller values of $qE$ it takes very large time.

```
g[x_] = (1 + 
      1/(4 a^4) (8 a^2 (a z - Log[1 + a z]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + 
            qM^2) (a z (6 - a z) + 2 (-3 - 2 a z + a^2 z^2) Log[1 + a z] + 
            2 Log[1 + a z]^2) + 
         2 a^2 (a z (4 - a z) + 2 Log[z] (a z (-2 + a z) + 2 Log[1 + a z]) + 
            4 PolyLog[2, -a z])) - 
      1/(a zh (-2 + a zh) + 
        2 Log[1 + a zh]) (a z (-2 + a z) + 2 Log[1 + a z]) (1 + 
         1/(4 a^4) (8 a^2 (a zh - Log[1 + a zh]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + 
               qM^2) (a zh (6 - a zh) + 
               2 (-3 - 2 a zh + a^2 zh^2) Log[1 + a zh] + 
               2 Log[1 + a zh]^2) + 
            2 a^2 (a zh (4 - a zh) + 
               2 Log[zh] (a zh (-2 + a zh) + 2 Log[1 + a zh]) + 
               4 PolyLog[2, -a zh])))) /. z -> x /. zh -> xh;

A[x_] = -Log[1 + a x];
F[x_] = g[x]/x^2;
G[x_] = g[x]/(x^2 Exp[2 A[x]])

(* (1/(x^2))(1 + a x)^2 (1 + (
   8 a^2 (a x - Log[1 + a x]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + qM^2) (a x (6 - a x) + 
       2 (-3 - 2 a x + a^2 x^2) Log[1 + a x] + 2 Log[1 + a x]^2) + 
    2 a^2 (a x (4 - a x) + 2 Log[x] (a x (-2 + a x) + 2 Log[1 + a x]) + 
       4 PolyLog[2, -a x]))/(
   4 a^4) - ((a x (-2 + a x) + 2 Log[1 + a x]) (1 + (
      8 a^2 (a xh - Log[1 + a xh]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + 
          qM^2) (a xh (6 - a xh) + 2 (-3 - 2 a xh + a^2 xh^2) Log[1 + a xh] + 
          2 Log[1 + a xh]^2) + 
       2 a^2 (a xh (4 - a xh) + 
          2 Log[xh] (a xh (-2 + a xh) + 2 Log[1 + a xh]) + 
          4 PolyLog[2, -a xh]))/(4 a^4)))/(a xh (-2 + a xh) + 2 Log[1 + a xh])
   ) *)

Scoeff = -((x^4 G[x])/(x - xh));
Scoeffa0 = Series[Scoeff, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal

(* -((x^2 (-4 x^2 - 4 x xh - 4 xh^2 - 4 x^2 xh^2 + qE^2 x^3 xh^3 + 
    qM^2 x^3 xh^3))/(4 xh^3)) *)

Clear[xh]
Scoeffa0 /. qE -> 0 /. qM -> 0 // Expand

(* x^4/xh^3 + x^3/xh^2 + x^2/xh + x^4/xh *)

tcoeff = -2 x^3 G[x] - 2 I x^2 ω Sqrt[G[x]/F[x]] - (
   x^4 G[x] Derivative[1][F][x])/(2 F[x]) - 1/2 x^4 Derivative[1][G][x];

tcoeffa0 = Series[tcoeff, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal // Expand

(* -2 x^3 - qE^2 x^5 - qM^2 x^5 + (3 x^4)/xh^3 + (3 x^4)/xh + 3/4 qE^2 x^4 xh + 3/4 qM^2 x^4 xh - 2 I x^2 ω *)

ucoeff = L x^3 + L^2 x^3 - L x^2 xh - L^2 x^2 xh - (
    x^4 G[x] Derivative[1][F][x])/(2 F[x]) + (
    x^3 xh G[x] Derivative[1][F][x])/(2 F[x]) - 1/2 x^4 Derivative[1][G][x] + 
    1/2 x^3 xh Derivative[1][G][x] // Simplify;

ucoeffa0 = Series[ucoeff, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal // Expand;
```

QNM Calculation

````
Clear[qE, qM, s, t, u, Sn, Tn, Un, P, aa, ex, expressao, rh, xh]

L = 0;
qM = 0;
qE = 5;
(*a=0.01;*)
rh = 2; xh = 1/rh;
s[x_] = Scoeffa0 // Simplify
t[x_, ω_] = tcoeffa0 // Simplify
u[x_] = ucoeffa0 // Simplify

(* 
1/4 x^2 (8 + 16 x + 40 x^2 - 25 x^3)
-2 x^3 + (315 x^4)/8 - 25 x^5 - 2 I x^2 ω
-1 + 2 x - (105 x^3)/16 + (155 x^4)/8 - (25 x^5)/2 *)

Sn = Function[n, SeriesCoefficient[Series[s[x], {x, xh, n}], n]];
Tn = Function[n, SeriesCoefficient[Series[t[x, ω], {x, xh, n}], n]];
Un = Function[n, SeriesCoefficient[Series[u[x], {x, xh, n}], n]];

P = Function[{n, ω}, n (n - 1) Sn[0] + n Tn[0]];

Clear[aa, Nit, ex]
aa[0] = 1;
Nit = 100;
 aa[n_] := 
  aa[n] = Simplify[-1/
      P[n, ω] Sum[(k (k - 1) Sn[n - k] + k Tn[n - k] + Un[n - k]) aa[
        k], {k, 0, n - 1}]];

ex[n_] := ex[n] = Sum[aa[i]*(-xh)^i, {i, 0, n}];
expressao := Sum[aa[i]*(-xh)^(i), {i, 0, Nit}]

QNMs = FindRoot[expressao == 0, {ω, 100 - 200*I}, AccuracyGoal -> 10][[1]][[2]]
wroots = SolveValues[expressao == 0, ω] // N```
````

Comment: This depends entirely on the actual problem being solved. If you can share a minimum working example of the kind of problem that's giving you trouble and what you have tried to do to solve it yourself, it will be much easier for people to help you.

Comment: This won’t be viable without an example.

Comment: The question has been reopened, but I would suggest the following. The inclusion of `In[]`/`Out[]` means the code cannot be copied, pasted, and executed in Mma. If you remove them, you will be much more likely to get someone to examine and test your code.  Further, a fairly common practice is to put output between comment markers `(* ... *)` so that the output won't be executed if it is pasted into Mma. If you don't make these edits, then each person who tries to help you will have to make the edits themselves. Or they can just skip the question, whichever seems a better use of their time.

Comment: Is this the same question as this one?
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/287322/72953

Answer (score 2):

The code runs for me in 3-4 mins with `Nit=100`. The only thing I changed was the `WorkingPrecision` in `FindRoot` and `SolveValues` (since you want numerical approximations anyways). I also removed `ex` because it's unused.

```
(*all the same code as yours*)

(*...until here*)
ClearAll[expressao]
AbsoluteTiming[
 expressao := Sum[aa[i]*(-xh)^(i), {i, 0, Nit}];
 QNMs = FindRoot[expressao == 0, {\[Omega], 100 - 200*I}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 64][[1]][[2]];
 wroots = 
  SolveValues[expressao == 0, \[Omega], WorkingPrecision -> 128];
 ]
```

> `{221.373, Null}`

And verifying the roots:

```
Chop[expressao /. \[Omega] -> QNMs]
Chop[expressao /. \[Omega] -> wroots]
```

> `0`

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Answer (score 0):

This might not fully solve your problem, but I believe it's worth the try:

All the functions you are using here are holomorphic functions (in fact, I think I only saw hyper-geometric ones). This means that you can re-write everything in the form:
$$S(x)=\sum_n a_n x^n$$
and in fact, even in the form
$$S(x)=\sum_{n_1,n_2,n_3} a_{n_1,n_2,n_3} x^{n_1} a^{n_2} h^{n_3}$$
if it turns out you want to try several values of $a$ and $h$.

The nice thing about (actually) computing everything in this form is that the coefficients $a_n$ are always the same between each execution. This gives you the luxury of storing them somewhere, so that you only have to compute them once (after that, the complexity is only that of reading data in a file, (i.e. $\mathcal{O}(1)$). As for the changing part of the computation (i.e. the "$x^n$") it can be recursively stored at each step so that you are computing it also in $\mathcal{O}(1)$, bringing your total computation of a quick $\mathcal{O}(N)$ (where $N$ is the number of terms in your series). Worst case scenario (if you go to higher $N$s each time, the fact that your series is hypergeometric means each terms can be computed using the previous, meaning the total computation is still $\mathcal{O}(N)$ (provided you are computing in floats, if you are computing in exact values, your numerator and denominator of $a_n$ are going to blow up like as products of factorials, and so the reduction of the fraction is going to tremendously slow your computer down). But in any case, you will only have to do that once for each term since you end up storing it.

The bad thing about this otherwise ideal method (in spite of all the pain you are going to go through while figuring out what $a_n$ is) is that $S$ has a radius of convergence (or two, if you are doing a Laurent expansion). This means that if you are computing for $x$ sometimes inside the convergence area and sometimes not then you need to use another series. And there's no telling how many of these you'll need (potentially: an infinite number; worst case: one for each of the values you want to try) and that quite defeats the purpose of using series in the first place.

To conclude with the way to proceed:

- first consider the full range over which you want to evaluate.
- try to see if you can find singularities in your function; they are a good indicator of the size of your convergence area; if they are close $\to$ small areas; if there are none $\to$ infinite area (but I've seen some polylogs so I doubt it will be the case :-(... This should help you estimate whether or not computing the series seems worth it.
- if it looks decent, compute the series, verify that if does converge where you want to; and then implement the method.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Although I have not evaluated the math, nevertheless this answer does not address any Mathematica coding aspect. It could be improved by adding code or Mathematica applications, if possible and relevant.

Comment: True, there is no Mathematica script... Sorry if that causes disappointment. I was only addressing the speed issue and trying to come up with a way to improve the current algorithm; and it is indeed independent of the coding language. I might add some code another day, but it first requires a lot of math (as described in the answer) the outcome of which depends on information which I do not posses (for example, as addressed in the answer, the values taken by $x$).