# How to make faster of a code containing more iteration point?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, evaluation, numerical-value, iteration

I am trying to evaluate a code of the Power Series Solution method to get the results. Also, the time of evaluation depends on the parameters I am using. When the iteration point is 50, 60, or 80, it takes less time(10 mins to 1 hour) than when the iteration point is 100 or 120(like two to three days). So is there any code that makes it faster to get the result?
Here is an example. When I am giving the iteration value 100, it takes two days whereas in the case of 40, 50, or 80 it takes 15-20 mins, and for smaller values of $qE$ it takes very large time.

```
Quit[]
g[x_] = (1 + 
      1/(4 a^4) (8 a^2 (a z - Log[1 + a z]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + 
            qM^2) (a z (6 - a z) + 2 (-3 - 2 a z + a^2 z^2) Log[1 + a z] + 
            2 Log[1 + a z]^2) + 
         2 a^2 (a z (4 - a z) + 2 Log[z] (a z (-2 + a z) + 2 Log[1 + a z]) + 
            4 PolyLog[2, -a z])) - 
      1/(a zh (-2 + a zh) + 
        2 Log[1 + a zh]) (a z (-2 + a z) + 2 Log[1 + a z]) (1 + 
         1/(4 a^4) (8 a^2 (a zh - Log[1 + a zh]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + 
               qM^2) (a zh (6 - a zh) + 
               2 (-3 - 2 a zh + a^2 zh^2) Log[1 + a zh] + 
               2 Log[1 + a zh]^2) + 
            2 a^2 (a zh (4 - a zh) + 
               2 Log[zh] (a zh (-2 + a zh) + 2 Log[1 + a zh]) + 
               4 PolyLog[2, -a zh])))) /. z -> x /. zh -> xh;

A[x_] = -Log[1 + a x];

F[x_] = g[x]/x^2;
G[x_] = g[x]/(x^2 Exp[2 A[x]])
```

> ```
> (1/(x^2))(1 + a x)^2 (1 + (
>    8 a^2 (a x - Log[1 + a x]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + qM^2) (a x (6 - a x) + 
>        2 (-3 - 2 a x + a^2 x^2) Log[1 + a x] + 2 Log[1 + a x]^2) + 
>     2 a^2 (a x (4 - a x) + 2 Log[x] (a x (-2 + a x) + 2 Log[1 + a x]) + 
>        4 PolyLog[2, -a x]))/(
>    4 a^4) - ((a x (-2 + a x) + 2 Log[1 + a x]) (1 + (
>       8 a^2 (a xh - Log[1 + a xh]) + (-2 a^2 + qE^2 + 
>           qM^2) (a xh (6 - a xh) + 2 (-3 - 2 a xh + a^2 xh^2) Log[1 + a xh] + 
>           2 Log[1 + a xh]^2) + 
>        2 a^2 (a xh (4 - a xh) + 
>           2 Log[xh] (a xh (-2 + a xh) + 2 Log[1 + a xh]) + 
>           4 PolyLog[2, -a xh]))/(4 a^4)))/(a xh (-2 + a xh) + 2 Log[1 + a xh])
>    )
> ```

```
Scoeff = -((x^4 G[x])/(x - xh));
Scoeffa0 = Series[Scoeff, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal
```

> ```
> -((x^2 (-4 x^2 - 4 x xh - 4 xh^2 - 4 x^2 xh^2 + qE^2 x^3 xh^3 + 
>     qM^2 x^3 xh^3))/(4 xh^3))
> ```

```
Clear[xh]
Scoeffa0 /. qE -> 0 /. qM -> 0 // Expand
```

> ```
> x^4/xh^3 + x^3/xh^2 + x^2/xh + x^4/xh
> ```

```
tcoeff = -2 x^3 G[x] - 2 I x^2 \[Omega] Sqrt[G[x]/F[x]] - (
   x^4 G[x] Derivative[1][F][x])/(2 F[x]) - 1/2 x^4 Derivative[1][G][x];

tcoeffa0 = Series[tcoeff, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal // Expand
```

> ```
> -2 x^3 - qE^2 x^5 - qM^2 x^5 + (3 x^4)/xh^3 + (3 x^4)/xh + 3/4 qE^2 x^4 xh + 
>  3/4 qM^2 x^4 xh - 2 I x^2 \[Omega]
> ```

```
ucoeff = L x^3 + L^2 x^3 - L x^2 xh - L^2 x^2 xh - (
    x^4 G[x] Derivative[1][F][x])/(2 F[x]) + (
    x^3 xh G[x] Derivative[1][F][x])/(2 F[x]) - 1/2 x^4 Derivative[1][G][x] + 
    1/2 x^3 xh Derivative[1][G][x] // Simplify;

ucoeffa0 = Series[ucoeff, {a, 0, 0}] // Normal // Expand;
```

QNM Calculation

```
Clear[qE, qM, s, t, u, Sn, Tn, Un, P, aa, ex, expressao, rh, xh]

L = 0;
qM = 0;
qE = 5;
(*a=0.01;*)

rh = 2; xh = 1/rh;

s[x_] = Scoeffa0 // Simplify
t[x_, \[Omega]_] = tcoeffa0 // Simplify
u[x_] = ucoeffa0 // Simplify
```

> ```
> 1/4 x^2 (8 + 16 x + 40 x^2 - 25 x^3)
> -2 x^3 + (315 x^4)/8 - 25 x^5 - 2 I x^2 \[Omega]
> -1 + 2 x - (105 x^3)/16 + (155 x^4)/8 - (25 x^5)/2
> ```

```
Sn = Function[n, SeriesCoefficient[Series[s[x], {x, xh, n}], n]];
Tn = Function[n, SeriesCoefficient[Series[t[x, \[Omega]], {x, xh, n}], n]];
Un = Function[n, SeriesCoefficient[Series[u[x], {x, xh, n}], n]];

P = Function[{n, \[Omega]}, n (n - 1) Sn[0] + n Tn[0]];

Clear[aa, Nit, ex]

aa[0] = 1;
Nit = 100;
 aa[n_] := 
  aa[n] = Simplify[-1/
      P[n, \[Omega]] Sum[(k (k - 1) Sn[n - k] + k Tn[n - k] + Un[n - k]) aa[
        k], {k, 0, n - 1}]];

ex[n_] := ex[n] = Sum[aa[i]*(-xh)^i, {i, 0, n}];

expressao := Sum[aa[i]*(-xh)^(i), {i, 0, Nit}]

QNMs = FindRoot[expressao == 0, {\[Omega], 100 - 200*I}, AccuracyGoal -> 10][[
   1]][[2]]
wroots = SolveValues[expressao == 0, \[Omega]] // N
```

Comment: Your [previous (identical) question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287291/how-to-make-faster-of-a-code-containing-more-iteration-points) was closed for a lack of clarity. Please do not simply open a new question with the same content. Instead, edit the original question to include the requested details, and ask for it to be reopened

Comment: @LukasLang I have already edited the Question but I didn't get any response so I thought there might be some problem, that's why I asked again.

Comment: Is the "iteration point" (which you said is 100 in this case) `Nit`?

Answer (score 2):

I may be completely off the mark here, but I believe this produces all the output you want. This should also work for your original code without any modification, except replacing `SolveValues[expressao == 0, \[Omega]]//N` with `Solve[expressao == 0, \[Omega], WorkingPrecision -> 64]]`. I modified the definitions of `Sn`, `Tn` and `Un` to be closed form expressions (because there is an interesting form to the function I defined `summand` that may lead to further simplification) I also reduced `Nit` to 80 as `Nit=100` would probably still take too long to run:

```
(*Sn=Function[n,SeriesCoefficient[Series[s[x],{x,xh,n}],n]];
Tn=Function[n,SeriesCoefficient[Series[t[x,\[Omega]],{x,xh,n}],n]];
Un=Function[n,SeriesCoefficient[Series[u[x],{x,xh,n}],n]];
P=Function[{n,\[Omega]},n (n-1) Sn[0]+n Tn[0]];*)
Sn[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[s[x], {x, xh, n}];
Tn[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[t[x, \[Omega]], {x, xh, n}];
Un[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[u[x], {x, xh, n}];
P = Function[{n, \[Omega]}, n (n - 1) Sn[0] + n Tn[0]];

Clear[aa, Nit, ex]

aa[0] = 1;
Nit = 80;

(*aa[n_] := 
  aa[n] = Simplify[-1/
      P[n, \[Omega]] Sum[(k (k - 1) Sn[n - k] + k Tn[n - k] + 
         Un[n - k]) aa[k], {k, 0, n - 1}]];

*)

summand[n_, k_] = 
PiecewiseExpand[(k (k - 1) Sn[n - k] + k Tn[n - k] + Un[n - k])] // 
   FullSimplify;
aa[n_] := 
  aa[n] = Simplify[-1/P[n, \[Omega]] Sum[
      summand[n, k]* aa[k], {k, 0, n - 1}]];
```

With `Nit=80`, it takes under a minute to calculate the sum `expressao`:

```
{timing, expressao} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[Sum[aa[i]*(-xh)^(i), {i, 0, Nit}]];
timing
(*41.322*)
```

Note there may also be a way to really speed this up since `summand` is nonzero only for $n-k = 0,1,2,3,4,5$  (this is due to the fact that `s`,`x`,and `u` are all quintic polynomials in $x$):

$summand[n,k] = \begin{cases}
 -\frac{25}{4} (k+1) (k+2) & k+5=n \\
 -\frac{5}{8} (k+1) (9 k+19) & k+4=n \\
 \frac{1}{16} (2 k (67 k+47)+15) & k+3=n \\
 \frac{1}{64} (k (515 k+149)+183)-2 i k \omega  & k+1=n \\
 \frac{1}{32} (115+2 k (243 k-32 i \omega +154)) & k+2=n \\
 \frac{1}{128} n (183 n-64 i \omega ) & k=n \\
 0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

`FindRoot` only takes a few seconds to run here. I added extra `WorkingPrecision` to satisfy warnings generated by `FindRoot`. We also see that the value returned by `FindRoot` is indeed close to 0:

```
FindRoot[expressao == 0, {\[Omega], 100 - 200*I}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 64]
fVal = N[expressao /. %, 64]
(*{\[Omega] -> \
-39.62472899711799040310877599484101002624482428359801909627376901 - 
   204.2008794030038908985991118381199145550361428016356649295629244 \
I}*)
(*0.*10^-20 + 0.*10^-20 I*)
```

And also just to be sure, checking that `fVal` has good accuracy:

```
fVal // InputForm
(*0``19.22568095272829 + 0``19.225637021348017*I*)
```

For the `SolveValues` part, since you want numerical values anyways, you can just add the option `WorkingPrecision->64` and get results in about 8s:

```
{wTiming, wroots} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   Solve[expressao == 0, \[Omega], WorkingPrecision -> 64]];
wTiming
(*7.9859*)
```

Then check that the values are indeed roots:

```
Abs[expressao /. wroots] // Chop
(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.*10^-9, 0.*10^-5, 
 0.*10^-3, 0.*10^-3, 
 0.*10^-5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)
```

We see all the values are sufficiently close to zero (but a few have low accuracy).

I haven't tried this with `Nit=100`, and I'm not really sure how much longer that would take.

**Update**
For `Nit=100`, `expressao` takes a little over 3 minutes:

```
{timing, expressao} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[Sum[aa[i]*(-xh)^(i), {i, 0, Nit}]];
timing
(*198.784*)
```

And finding `wroots` takes about 17s. Some of the roots had bad accuracy with `WorkingPrecision->64` so I increased it to 128 and got good results:

```
{wTiming, wroots} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   Solve[expressao == 0, \[Omega], WorkingPrecision -> 128]];
wTiming
Abs[expressao /. wroots] // Chop

(*17.0907*)
(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)
```